# Cross validating QDA classifer in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Is it not possible to call `cross_val_score` function on the QDA classifer in sklearn?
This is my snippet:

```
cvKF = cross_validation.KFold(len(communications.target), n_folds=3, shuffle=True)
clf_qda = QDA()
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf_qda, myData.data, myData.target, cv=cvKF)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
  File "/Users/t/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/qda.py", line 149, in _decision_function
    return (-0.5 * (norm2 + np.sum(np.log(self.scalings_), 1))

AttributeError: log
```

Any thought? is it a bug or something wrong by my side?

Comment: Confirmed, this must be a bug -- not sure what's causing it, though.

Comment: Ah, found it: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3721

Comment: Isn't this https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4006 ? It will be fixed in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4057 then.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the version 0.16.dev (on development yet) and this bug was solved. See github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn